# R Reshape data twice

Tags: r, reshape, transpose

I have trouble reshaping my dataset correctly: I have some IVs and then 60 columns containing repeated measures (10 times) data of 6 blocks. Hence, I want to reshape the data to create **one** dependent variable and an additional new timevariable (1-10) and a new variable containing the information of the block (1-6).

I already tried reshaping twice, but I failed. The data looks like:

```
 sbj  someIV    OfferCero.1   OfferCero.2 OfferCero.3 .... OfferFive.1 OfferFive.10 
   1   10         6               1           4                 1           4
   2   12         5               7           1                 2           3
   3   20         7               2           8                 5           2
   4   22         8               2           4                 4           1
```

and should look like:

```
sbj  someIV    DV     Timepoint     Offersize
 1   10         6         1             0         
 1   10         1         2             0
 1   10         4         3             0
 1   10         5         4             0
```

My code so far:

```
First Reshape:

dl <- reshape(df, varying=list(CeroCent= c(32:41), OneCent= c(42:51), TwoCent= c(52:61), ThreeCent= c(62:71),FourCent= c(72:81), FiveCent= c(82:91) ), 
        v.names=c("CeroCent", "OneCent", "TwoCent", "ThreeCent", "FourCent", "FiveCent"),           
        direction="long",  
        times=1:10,
        timevar="Timepoint")

Second One: 
dl2 <- reshape(dl, direction="long", 
               varying= c(33:38),
               v.names="Emotion",
               times = 1:6, timevar="Offer")
```

And some example data (only two "blocks" of 5 repetitions):

```
example <- data.frame(
  Sub = c(1:5),
  IV1 = sample(1:5),
  IV2 = sample(1:5),
  CeroCent.1 = sample(1:5),
  CeroCent.2 = sample(1:5),
  CeroCent.3 = sample(1:5),
  CeroCent.4 = sample(1:5),
  CeroCent.5 = sample(1:5),
  FiveCent.1 = sample(1:5),
  FiveCent.2 = sample(1:5),
  FiveCent.3 = sample(1:5),
  FiveCent.4 = sample(1:5),
  FiveCent.5 = sample(1:5)
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: And also include a reproducible example, not just a view of your code that we cant run. [Reproducible example](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=r+reproducible+example&oq=r+reprod&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j35i39j0l3.3319j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but I think this is what you're looking for. Let me know if this isn't right. I haven't recoded the factor levels in the "Timepoint" column; I'll leave that as an exercise to you

```
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)
mydata <- gather(example, key = "temp", value = "DV", -Sub, -IV1, 
                 -IV2) %>% 
  separate(temp, c("Timepont", "Offersize"))
```

Gives output of

```
  Sub IV1 IV2 Timepont Offersize DV
   1   4   3 CeroCent         1  4
   2   3   1 CeroCent         1  1
   3   1   2 CeroCent         1  2
   4   5   4 CeroCent         1  5
   5   2   5 CeroCent         1  3
   1   4   3 CeroCent         2  3
```

Comment: Great, this is what i was looking for! Thank you very much

Comment: No worries, thank you for taking the time to improve your question